# i have this model how do i make the outline above the solid texture?

Tags: materials

I want to have the outline be above the torso but behind the visor, tips? (pic left is wanted, pic right is what i get.(among us hahahahaahaahah)) [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a curve that goes around the glass part, and give it some thickness with a profile ?

Create a curve (I used a boolean modifier, then isolated the intesecting edge)
[image]

Give it somee thickness with a profile
[image]

And voilà, Parmi Nous.
[image]

Comment: would be great, but not so great for animating as far as i know